# Summation of numpy arrays, which method is better to use?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between 3 following methods and which one is better to use?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([2, 1])

sum(a*b) # mtd 1
(a*b).sum() # mtd 2
np.sum(a*b) # mtd 3
```

Comment: Methods 2 and 3 are equivalent. Don't use method 1 - the `sum` builtin is not optimised for NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The best one is `np.dot(a, b)` which is meant exactly for the operation you are performing: multiply the entries of a by entries of b, and add them up.

As for `np.sum(array)` vs `array.sum()`, these are two ways of expressing the same thing, both forms are provided for convenience.

As ajcr said, `sum(a*b)` is suboptimal because it's a plain Python method, not NumPy method. Python's `sum` has to handle all kinds of things present in Python lists. NumPy arrays are homogeneous, containing objects of the same type, so its methods take advantage of that.